# Is adapter-id unique among all network adapter vendors?

Tags: windows, networking

Wanted to know if adapter-id is unique among all network adapter vendors.

Comment: If you're talking about MAC addresses, it's supposed to be ex-factory, but I know of a case where the netadmin had to return a shipment of over 100 which all had the same MAC address.

Comment: I am trying to use one of the windows api's  in the below link which says network adapter id: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.networkadapterid.aspx

Comment: I don't code in C# but in winapi there are couple functions that also return GUID as "adapter id" (more like adapterName and InterfaceId), you can find this guid in \HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\{your guid} for what I have found out, this guid persists accross changes on your interface. I can't really back my claim up with any link, but I doubt it is based on vendor. It is unique though, you won't mix up two interfaces when using this.